# Can not connect release management client to visual studio team services

Tags: tfs, ms-release-management

I have problem to connect release management client to visual studio team services.

> 1. service user

[image]

> 2. Manage TFS

[image]

> 3. Error

[image]

I have only problem to connect with visual studio team services, but its working with team foundation service. Please help/guide me, where I am wrong, thanks for your valuable time and effort in advance.

Comment: It's a while since I connected RM classic to VSTS but the account you are using doesn't look like it's going to work. Try using the same account that you would use when connecting to VSTS in your browser.

Comment: thanks for your comment, can you point me what is missing or show me example with your account. but also i test it in browser its working.. http://smartmindsco.visualstudio.com/

Comment: I haven't used RM classic for so long now that I'd lost track of the fact that as per Daniel's answer it looks like the ability to connect to VSTS (or VSO as it was back then) from RM classic has been removed. Is there any reason you can't use the RM capabilities of VSTS?

Answer (score 3):

The Release Management client is for Release Management Server, the on-premise product. Visual Studio Team Services **does not** support that. The Release hub in VSTS is a completely separate, redesigned release experience. The on-premise Release Management Server product and the VSTS/TFS 2015.2 Release hub are completely different tools that serve the same purpose.

You should be using the Release hub in VSTS, not the Release Management server/client product.